# ItemsControl that contains bound ComboBox in ItemTemplate (WPF MVVM with Caliburn.Micro)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox, caliburn.micro, itemscontrol

I'm stuck with a problem to select one item in a single combo box from a list of combo boxes bound in a ItemTemplate. When I select a value in one, that value gets updated in all of them. It resembles this problem [ItemsControl that contains bound ComboBox in ItemTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987781/itemscontrol-that-contains-bound-combobox-in-itemtemplate) but I can't get what I'm missing.
Can someone help, please?

If need more code for clarification, just ask :)
Thank you!

ItemsControl:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
<ItemsControl x:Name="InputsList"
              Margin="15 10 10 5">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Components:InputUCView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

UserControl (with combobox)

```
<ComboBox x:Name="PdfListCombo"
      Style="{DynamicResource conditionalComboBox}"
      Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
      Margin="2 5 5 2" Text="Select pdf"
      ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={
                RelativeSource AncestorType={
                x:Type ItemsControl}},
                Path=DataContext.PdfListCombo}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={
                RelativeSource AncestorType={
                x:Type ItemsControl}},
                Path=DataContext.SelectedPdfName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

parts in question from ViewModel

```
private BindableCollection<InputModel> _inputsList;

public BindableCollection<InputModel> InputsList
{
   get
     {
    
       _inputsList = new(inputsList);
       return _inputsList;
     }
  set
    {
      _inputsList = value;
      NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => InputsList);
    }
  }


    private BindableCollection<string> _pdfListCombo;

    public BindableCollection<string> PdfListCombo
    {
        get
        {
            //_pdfListCombo ??= new();
            foreach (var item in inputsList)
            {
                List<string> pdfFiles = new();
                foreach (var pdf in item.PdfNames)
                {
                    pdfFiles.Add(Path.GetFileName(pdf));
                }
                _pdfListCombo=new(pdfFiles);
            }
            return _pdfListCombo;
        }
        set
        {
            _pdfListCombo = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => PdfListCombo);
        }
    }

    private string _selectedPdfName;

    public string SelectedPdfName
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedPdfName;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedPdfName = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedPdfName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your code

```
<ComboBox x:Name="PdfListCombo"
      Style="{DynamicResource conditionalComboBox}"
      Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
      Margin="2 5 5 2" Text="Select pdf"
      ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={
                RelativeSource AncestorType={
                x:Type ItemsControl}},
                Path=DataContext.PdfListCombo}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={
                RelativeSource AncestorType={
                x:Type ItemsControl}},
                Path=DataContext.SelectedPdfName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Your `ComboBox` binds the `ItemsSource` to the property `PdfListCombo` of the `DataContext` of the first found `ItemsControl` parent.
And `ComboBox` binds the `SelectedItem` to the property `SelectedPdfName` of the `DataContext` of the first found `ItemsControl` parent...........
[image]
TwoWays binding to same property of same object, that's caused your problem.

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately

Comment: @RazvanDumitrescu what's the `BindableCollection`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question.
Either the answer is - For ItemsControl, the BindableCollection is InputsList; for each input there is a UserControl with a label and a combobox, the combobox is bound to anothe BindableCollection with pdf names. It's right there in the code I uploaded.

Comment: Or - BindableCollection is the ObservableCollection of Caliburn.Micro (it derives from it) with some added features.

Meanwile I created a separate object for pdfs with its own list that fills that PdfCombo collection. IsSynchrronized still doesn't work. Either is selectedItem or SelectedValue, all combos are synchronized.

Comment: @RazvanDumitrescu If this setting is invalid, it means that your `Binding` situation may be more complicated and not common. Just a guess: maybe `BindableCollection` itself has the feature of synchronizing the binding target selected item. Check the documentation to see if there is a way to turn off this function, or simply use something simpler, an `ObservableCollection` or a `List`.

Comment: @RazvanDumitrescu Or, there is a more "stupid" mistake (and from your example code, I highly doubt this is the case), you mistakenly make all `ComboBox.SelectedItem` bound to one "shared" object property. Any ComboBox selection changed that updates this property, and will also notify all ComboBoxes bound to this property to update selected item.

Comment: It was exactly that, but it was not a mistake, it was my lack of experience (I'm a beginner)
I'll post an update of the solution shortly. Thanks, you were a big big help!

Comment: @RazvanDumitrescu Intersting is that I asked your quesion on new bing, The meaning of AI answer as same as me. I think you can consider asking AI these basic questions first. (But AI is not completely trustworthy, please be careful when trying the answers given by AI.)

Comment: The AI answer: https://sl.bing.net/cFCHbwTlVGm (just for example)

Answer (score 0):

As @Mr. Squirrel.Downy said, the issue was with the binding source being shared between all comboboxes (InputsList property) in a shared viewmodel for both main view and the usercontrol with combos. Thanks for your patience!

The correct way (at least for caliburn.micro) is to make a separate viewmodel for the usercontrol, populate a BindableCollection with it based on the number of inputs in that InputsList and bind the ItemsControl to that list.

Here is the code:

ItemsControl:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
<ItemsControl x:Name="InputVMList"
              Margin="15 10 10 5">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Components:InputUCView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

UserControl (combos):

```
            <ComboBox x:Name="FillListCombo"
                  Style="{DynamicResource commonComboBox}"
                  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
                  Margin="2 5 5 2"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FillListCombo}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedFillColor, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

            <ComboBox x:Name="PdfListCombo"
                  Style="{DynamicResource conditionalComboBox}"
                  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
                  Margin="2 5 5 2"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PdfListCombo}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="PdfName"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedPdfName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Collection in main viewmodel:

```
    private BindableCollection<InputUCViewModel> _inputVMList;

    public BindableCollection<InputUCViewModel> InputVMList
{
    get
    {
        _inputVMList ??= new();
        _inputVMList.AddRange(inputsUcVMList);
        return _inputVMList;
    }
    set
    {
        _inputVMList = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => InputVMList);
    }
}
```

Collection for ComboBoxes:

```
    private BindableCollection<PdfObjectModel> _pdfListCombo;

    public BindableCollection<PdfObjectModel> PdfListCombo
    {
        get
        {
            _pdfListCombo ??= new();
            _pdfListCombo.AddRange(_pdfObjList);
            return _pdfListCombo;
        }
        set
        {
            _pdfListCombo = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => PdfListCombo);
        }
    }

    private PdfObjectModel _selectedPdfName;

    public PdfObjectModel SelectedPdfName
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedPdfName;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedPdfName = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedPdfName);
        }
    }
```